# Conditional Operator false value seems to not run

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

HTML:

```
<a href="/u"><span>Text</span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><strong>Text</strong></span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><strong>Text</strong></span></a>
<a href="/u"><span>Text</span></a>


    var strong = $('span strong'),
        notstrong= $('span'),
        a = $('a[href^="/u"]');

         for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            var checkIt = strong ? strong : notstrong;
            $(a[i]).find(checkIt).before('<span>Hello</span>');
           }
```

OutCome Should Be :

```
<a href="/u"><span><span>Hello</span>Text</span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><span>Hello</span><strong>Text</strong></span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><span>Hello</span><strong>Text</strong></span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><span>Hello</span>Text</span></a>
```

Actual OutCome:

```
<a href="/u"><span>Text</span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><span>Hello</span><strong>Text</strong></span></a>
<a href="/u"><span><span>Hello</span><strong>Text</strong></span></a>
<a href="/u"><span>Text</span></a>
```

For some reason the conditional operator is not returning my false statement. That or the coding is wrong, as in I am using the wrong selector before. Is that true? I am curious on why my conditional operator is incorrect. I'm new at conditional operators so maybe it is always returning true or I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Wouldn't this always evaluate to being true?  Your operator doesn't distinguish between the lines.  It's simply checking to see strong exists anywhere, but then when you do your find it's always looking for strong.

Comment: `notstrong` contains **all** `<span>` elements, **including** those that contain a `<strong>` tag. also, `checkIt` will always be `strong` ... is that what you want?

Comment: Are you trying to add a `<span>Hello</span>` before all `<a><span>` elements text regardless of `<strong>`? It seems that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite know the end game, but if you're looking to determine whether or not something is strong in the context of the html block you have to give it more granular context.  By just checking to see if $('span strong') exists it will always return true. Even if you do $('span strong').length that will always return true because it is moving across the entire block.

Here's an example where the strong is check per line not per the entire block. so in this case it only return true when that line has a strong inside of it.

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var checkIt = $(a[i]).find(strong).length ? strong : notstrong;
  $(a[i]).find(checkIt).before('<span>Hello</span>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8XP4/

Comment: Your example works the best. Now I did just show a snippet of the code so everyone was just thinking I was crazy for this. It is a little more complicated than just what I show :D Thanks for understand Eric!

Answer (score 1):

`$('span strong')` returns a JavaScript object. JavaScript objects always equate to `true` because they are not undefined. What you want instead is the length property of said object.

```
var checkIt = strong.length ? strong : notstrong;
```

Edit: 
This still won't do what you want it to do, the logic error is deeper than this.

To accomplish the goal you presented, you can simply do this:

```
$('a[href^="/u"] strong').before('<span>Hello</span>');
```

Comment: Isn't this always going to evaluate to true?  if you do $('span strong') on that whole html block it's always going to find $('span strong')  He isn't doing a find inside of that particular line.

Comment: I may have figured out the solution please wait for an update

Answer (score 1):

If your problem isn't any more complicated than your code suggests, you could just do this:

```
$('a[href="/u"] > span').prepend('<span>Hello</span>');
```

Comment: Code is a little more complicated than just that ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the span to remain nested inside of it's original span when it finds a strong tag, you will have to change the method from before to prepend.

```
$('a[href^="/u"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span strong').length > 0){
        $(this).find('span strong').before('<span>Hello</span>');
        return false;
    }
    $(this).find('span').prepend('<span>Hello</span>')
});
```

If you do not prepend you will end up with a result of

```
<a href="/u">
   <span>Hello</span>
   <span>Text</span>
</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/u">
   <span>
      <span>Hello</span>
      "Text"
   </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, though I do have my answer already, also I __never__ use the .each() function ;) Thank you though